# how to grab optional values in to the edit form in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, forms, laravel-5

I am developing laravel application and submit some form data using form.blade.php file

```
 <select name="status" id="status">
                    <option value="">Choose a status</option>
                    <option value="Upcoming">Upcoming</option>
                    <option value="Active">Active</option>
                    <option value="Completed">Completed</option>
                </select>
                @if ($errors->has('status'))
                    <span class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('status') }}</span>
                @endif
```

and now I need edit this data using edit form and this is My edit form and grab values from table,

```
<select name="assign" id="status">
                    <option value="{!! $task->assign !!}">{!! $task->assign !!}</option>

                </select>
                @if ($errors->has('assign'))
                    <span class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('assign') }}</span>
                @endif
```

this is working but unable to select other optional values in the edit form optional values input. how can I fix this problem?

Comment: no any idea here

Comment: can you any body help me????

Answer (score 0):

John, you should use "multiple" attribute for select:

```html
<select name="status" id="status" multiple>
<!-- Options here -->
</select>
```

Comment: I need select edit form other optional value data witch other than select from database